# Android pressed button, accelerate count

Tags: java, android, loops, button, time

Ok, so, I'm trying to make a counter that counts up/down on each trigger of it's onClick() function.  Thing is I want it to accelerate the count when a X amount of time passes.

I think something like this should work:

```
Button button = new Button(context);
button.setOnTouchListener(new RepeatListener(1, 1, new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    /*
       count++;
       wait for some amount of time, lets call it timeX;
       if(timeX !< 100){ 
         timeX -= 10;
       }
    */
  }
}));
```

But I'm pretty sure there must be a function for what I'm trying to do.

And yes, before you comment on it, the initial and repeat intervals are the same. I want it to accelerate depending on how long you mantain the button/whatever pressed, up to a point of course.

Any ideas on how I could make it or which function should I use?  I could loop a "for" at my previous code but there must be some other way.  I'm kinda new to Android/Java :P

Answer (score 0):

you can add a touch listener in which you can get when button pressed on ACTION_DOWN and when released ACTION_UP  for example

```
  long lastPressed;
  long duration;

  button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //button pressed save the time
           lastPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } 
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           //button released calculate the time 
           duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastPressed;
        }
     }
  });
```